# Flutter - how to group notifications

Tags: flutter

i am using Flutter firebase messaging to receive notifications from backend, how to group notifications like android https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group?

Answer (score 6):

To group notifications in Flutter you can use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).
this package has many features and one of them is ([Android] Group notifications).
and to do so.

1. First, you should [setup](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications#initialisation) the package configurations.
2. Create GroupChannel in the same place you set the package configurations.

```
AndroidNotificationChannelGroup channelGroup = AndroidNotificationChannelGroup('com.my.app.alert1', 'mychannel1');
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannelGroup(channelGroup);
```

3. Create a [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98TotM_jNAs) to check if there are more than one active notification.

```
void groupNotifications() async {
  List<ActiveNotification>? activeNotifications = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.getActiveNotifications();

  if (activeNotifications != null && activeNotifications.length > 0) {
    List<String> lines = activeNotifications.map((e) => e.title.toString()).toList();
    InboxStyleInformation inboxStyleInformation = InboxStyleInformation(
      lines,
      contentTitle: "${activeNotifications.length - 1} Updates",
      summaryText: "${activeNotifications.length - 1} Updates",
    );
    AndroidNotificationDetails groupNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      channel.description,
      styleInformation: inboxStyleInformation,
      setAsGroupSummary: true,
      groupKey: channel.groupId,
      // onlyAlertOnce: true,
    );
    NotificationDetails groupNotificationDetailsPlatformSpefics = NotificationDetails(android: groupNotificationDetails);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, '', '', groupNotificationDetailsPlatformSpefics);
  }
}
```

Note:
you should call groupNotifications() every time notification recived

Comment: i can use for IOS device, too?

Comment: For iOS, you can specify threadIdentifier in IOSNotificationDetails. Notifications with the same threadIdentifier will get grouped together automatically.
[link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#grouping-notifications)

Comment: thanks, so how to message content displayed per user like chat app?

Comment: Not working correctly in the background.